# PostgreSQL: Effective way of grouping data by the number of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, architecture, grouping

#### Example

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE batches (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  total_value NUMERIC NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_batches (
  id             SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  batch_id       INT NOT NULL REFERENCES batches (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  transaction_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES transactions (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

- In the `transaction_batches` table transactions should be grouped in batches of N transactions
- User can delete or create transactions at any time
- If user has changed the transactions then the transaction batches must be rearranged (in order to ensure the batches of 20 transactions)

#### The goal

Effectively group the transactions in batches of N transactions with each transactions change by the user

#### Question

Could you please suggest a solution to achieve the goal?

**P.S.** You can suggest another tables structure

Comment: What is your query and expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there is no query, please see the question above

Answer (score 2):

I would simply do:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  batch_num INT NOT NULL
);
```

Set `batch_num` equal to:

```
SELECT floor((row_number() over (order by id) - 1) / N)
```

You can do this in a trigger.  Or you can simply use a view to calculate this when the table is queried.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value NUMERIC NOT NULL,
  batch_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES batches (id)
);

CREATE TABLE batches (
  id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  num_of_transactions INT,
  total_value NUMERIC NOT NULL
);
```

When user changes a transaction, we remove it from the batch as follows:

1. Set its batch_id to NULL
2. Decrease the num_of_transactions in the batch

Whenever we want to rearrange batches:

1. Find all batches for which num_of_transactions < N.
2. For each transaction that has batch_id=NULL, add it to the next batch that has a vacancy, updating the num_of_transactions of the batch, as well as the batch_id in the transaction.